# MobileFirst configuration for mapping service ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis, esri, ibm-mobilefirst

We are exploring IBM Mobilefirst capabilities with a mapping application. We are using Esri ArcGIS Mapping service.

Where can I find the available resources or sample tutorial to use Esri ArcGIS with IBM MobileFirst hybrid applications?

Answer (score 0):

Not every available tool out there has guides for IBM Worklight/MobileFirst.

It looks like Esri ArcgGIS has a developer website.
You should start there: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/sign-up/?origin=developer

Read how to integrate it into applications.
If there are SDKs then you will need to integrate those like you would any other SDK - that is outside of the Worklight/MFP scope (the integration).

I would assume that if it an SDK, you could then add a Cordova plug-in that would allow you to access that SDK from your app, or even better you could use the Send Action feature to bridge between Web and Native and vice versa.

- [Adding native functionality to hybrid applications with Apache Cordova](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/)
- [Action Sender](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_action_sender.html)